# certbot not renewing certificates

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a domain of the form `api.mydomain.com` with a letsencrypt certificate that I'm trying to renew.

```
root@prod-app-1:/home/ninesalt# certbot certificates
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Found the following certs:
  Certificate Name: api.mydomain.com
    Domains: api.mydomain.com
    Expiry Date: 2019-06-17 11:25:52+00:00 (VALID: 27 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

However when I try to renew it with `certbot renew` I get this error:

```
Attempting to renew cert (api.mydomain.com) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/api.mydomain.com.conf produced an unexpected error: The manual plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: PluginError('An authentication script must be provided with --manual-auth-hook when using the manual plugin non-interactively.',). Skipping.
All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem (failure)

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem (failure)
```

Answer (score 1):

Certificates that are created using `--manual` (and without an authentication hook) cannot be automatically renewed.

This is because it involves you performing the the authorization steps by hand, which is not something that Certbot can automatically repeat at renewal time.

Usually you will want to use an authenticator other than the manual one (such as --apache, --nginx, --webroot, --standalone), so that Certbot can perform automatic renewal.

So, you should probably manually create the certificate again:

```
certbot certonly --manual -d xxx.com
```